# Operator Precedence in naive mathematical logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Trying to negate a long logic expression, I encountered problems concerning operator precedence. As I was trying to google this I was only ever finding programming precedences and boolean precedences, but not for mathematical statements. Consider this:

$$ \neg (( A \implies B ) \lor (C) ) $$

How I would solve this is to first:

$$ \neg ( A \implies B ) \wedge \neg (C) $$

and then

$$ (A \wedge \neg B ) \wedge \neg (C) $$

This seems like the most logical order to me. **Could you please confirm if this is true and maybe provide some additional resources on operator precedence?**

The real problem is a lot more convoluted and I would like to know if my method to work from the "outer" layer to the "inner" layer is correct. Outer and inner layer shall her refer to the brackets.

Edit:

If we replace $$(A \implies B )$$ with $$ (\forall , y \in M : P(x) \wedge Q(y) \implies P(y) )$$ we yield:

$$ (\forall , y \in M : P(x) \wedge Q(y) \implies P(y) ) \lor (C)  $$

Trying to negate this new statement 
$$ \neg  (\forall , y \in M : P(x) \wedge Q(y) \implies P(y) ) \lor (C)  $$

in the same manner I get:

$$ (\forall , y \in M : P(x) \wedge Q(y) \wedge \neg P(y) ) \wedge \neg (C)  $$

Comment: There is no real precedence issue in this example, since it’s fully parenthesized. Your simplification is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much. I added the more convoluted statement where the precedence is not that obvious, at least to me. I still believe it to be correct, although I'm not sure. Could you please confirm this?

Comment: The problem here is that $\forall y\in M\,\big(P(x)\land Q(y)\to P(y)\big)$ isn’t actually of the form $A\to B$: the implication is inside the quantifier. You want $$\neg\forall y\in M\,\big(P(x)\land Q(y)\to P(y)\big)\land\neg C\;,$$ which is equivalent to $$\exists y\in M\,\Big(\neg\big(P(x)\land Q(y)\to P(y)\big)\Big)\land\neg C$$ and hence to $$\exists y\in M\,\big(P(x)\land Q(y)\land\neg P(y)\big)\land\neg C\;.$$

Comment: Looking to properly format my response, I postet an additional answer for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I could not properly format my comment, therefore I'm commenting in response to Mr. Scott in this answer.

Are these two statements equivalent?

$$ (\forall , y \in M : P(x) \wedge Q(y) \implies P(y) )$$ 
$$ \forall , y \in M ( P(x) \wedge Q(y) \implies P(y) )  $$

Comment: I’ve never seen a comma used that way, but if you removed the comma from both statements, they would indeed say the same thing in different notational formalisms.

Comment: That is a typo on my part, it was not included in the original statement that I was trying to negate. Thank you for your help, I truly learned a lot.

Comment: You’re welcome!